# How to amplify voltage using op-amp

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, operational-amplifier, motor

I want to measure a motor's load by it's current draw using Arduino, so I made this diagram:
[image]

The Motor is controlled by a L298 H-bridge.

My questions are :

1. The motor's rotation can be reversed, so the voltage on resistor R5 can be reversed, how the LM358 to deal with this? how to modify the diagram to implement this?
2. Is there any other errors on the diagram? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Depends how you're reversing the motor. -12V? H-bridge? DPDT switch? In 2 of these you can arrange that the voltage across R5 doesn't reverse; in the other, you have -V available for the opamp. Also note you're biasin the - input to 2.5V but referring your + input to 0V. That won't work.

Comment: I'm using a L298 H-bridge to reverse the motor. so, how to correct it? many thanks.

Comment: You have positive feedback on your opamp. Show where the h bridge is too.

Comment: When the opamp is intended to operate as a linear amplifier you must apply NEGATIVE feedback!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schematic will not work, because the voltage polarity in motor can reverse. I suggest use two op-amps as differential amplifier.

This is the example circuit. With this circuit, for the first op-amp, keep R3 = R4 and R2 = R5, and the output voltage:

\$ \Large V_{out} = \frac{R_5}{R_3} \times V_r \$

For the second op-amp, keep R7 = R8 and R6 = R9, and the output voltage:

\$ \Large V_{out} = \frac{R_9}{R_7} \times V_r \$

Vr is the voltage in R-sense. Vout can not be negative. So you can detect polarity by measuring output voltage of first and second op-amp. In any directions, one op-amp will give voltage near zero, and the other op-amp give voltage measurement of R-sense.

You can adjust value of R in op-amp to amplify the voltage of R-sense in order to suit the ADC of microcontroller.

[image]

Comment: I agree this should work, do note however that in this circuit the motor uses a different (separate) supply ! The ground of the opamps is NOT connected to the ground of the 12 V battery !

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed make your own circuit for this but that requires some knowledge of opamps and how to use them.

Therefore I would like to suggest to use a small module like this [5A Range ACS712 Current Sensor Arduino Eletronic Module](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/5A-Range-ACS712-Current-Sensor-Arduino-Eletronic-Module-/141742302156?hash=item21007fe3cc%5C) it uses the Hall effect to measure the current.

It is cheap and should be suitable for your needs and also it is easy to use with an Arduino. The motor current pins are also isolated from the interface pins so you can use it with a shared supply or separate supplies just as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to you all. I found another solution, hope this can avoid to measuring reverse voltage.:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's how to avoid the voltage reversal with a bridge.